# Trying to access Sharepoint remotely

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I've found multiple sites that tell me how to access a Sharepoint site remotely but none seem to explain let alone answer what I am experiencing.

1. I created a simple C# console app
2. Within the app I reference:
    `Microsoft.Sharepoint`, 
    `Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client`, and
    `Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.Runtime`
3. I am able to create using statements for `Microsoft.Sharepoint` and `Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client` but I do not get intellisense for `Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.Runtime` (I only get Applications, Utilities, WebParts and Workflow in the drop down window) -- If I type in using `Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.Runtime`, I get the "red squiggles" under Runtime
4. Commenting out the `Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.Runtime`, I then enter the following code:

   ```
   const string FORMAT = "{0}: {1}";
   string strURL = "http://<the SPS site address>";
   List<string> listFields = new List<string>();

   using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite(strURL))
   {
       using (SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb())
       {
           foreach (SPList list in oWeb.Lists)
           {
               foreach (SPField field in list.Fields)
               {
                   listFields.Add(string.Format(FORMAT, list.ID, field.Title));
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   Note: At this point in time, there are no errors reported in the error list
5. I then compile the code (Rebuild) -- At that point I get:

   1. Squiggles in both "Sharepoint" using statements
   2. Five (5) errors stating:

      - 'Sharepoint' does not exist in the namespace "Microsoft" (are you missing an assembly reference?) 2X
      - 'SPSite' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 2X
      - 'SPWeb' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference) 1X

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your expanded "References" section from the Solution Explorer window?

Answer (score 1):

If you're not developing on a computer with SharePoint installed on it you can't use those SSOM objects.

You should use their CSOM equivalent.

SPSite - Site

SPWeb - Web

SPList - List

Check out [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee537855.aspx) for other objects.

You will only need the reference to `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client`

Here's an example from MSDN to retrieve items from a list:

```
            string siteUrl = "http://MyServer/sites/MySiteCollection";

            ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
            SP.List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Announcements");

            CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
            camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name='ID'/>" +
                "<Value Type='Number'>10</Value></Geq></Where></Query><RowLimit>100</RowLimit></View>";
            ListItemCollection collListItem = oList.GetItems(camlQuery);

            clientContext.Load(collListItem);

            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            foreach (ListItem oListItem in collListItem)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ID: {0} \nTitle: {1} \nBody: {2}", oListItem.Id, oListItem["Title"], oListItem["Body"]);
            }
```